# How are bitmaps assembled in Android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm currently developing a (very) simple Android app which draws the Mandelbrot set on the screen and allows the user to zoom in on specified regions of the set. Up until now what I did to display the set was to calculate the color of each pixel of the screen (under a suitable coordinate transformation) with the help of two nested for loops:

```
int mandelPixels[] = new int[ canvas.width() * canvas.height() ];
index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= canvas.getHeight(); i++){
  for(int j = 0; j <= canvas.getWidth(); j++){

  // *** do the calculations to decide color of the pixel in question ***
  mandelPixels[index] = some color;      

  index++;
  }

}
```

As you can see I'm using the index variable as a way to consecutively fill the mandelPixels array (which holds the color int's of each Pixel in the plot). The implicit assumption here is, that when using

```
 bc = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
 Bitmap.createBitmap(mandelPixels, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), bc);
```

the bitmap will be created from the array *line by line*, that is the color int's index[0] to index[canvas.getWidth()] make up the first line and so on.

This actually works. However, I'm a little puzzled as to why this never gets mentioned in the android documentation. Is this the common way to assemble a bitmap from scratch?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Maybe read the last paragraph again.